# Error when trying to run carthage

Tags: ios, swift, terminal, carthage

I tried to setup my dependencies for a new iOS project. I wanted to use carthage for that.

I setup a Cartfile in the root directory of my project

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" >= 1.2
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON" >= 2.2
```

and then ran carthage update, getting this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TMdVSs9Character
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/carthage/0.7.3/bin/../Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks//PrettyColors.framework/PrettyColors
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
 in /usr/local/Cellar/carthage/0.7.3/bin/../Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks//PrettyColors.framework/PrettyColors
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I tried looking around but I couldn't find anything looking like this error.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling carthage (with homebrew) but nothing changed.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found the solution here :

https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/330

**Steps:**

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework
rm -f /usr/local/bin/carthage
brew uninstall carthage
brew install carthage
```

Comment: I wonder why this is missed from the `README.md`... considering that it's not enough to just remove `/Library/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework` as the readme states...

Comment: Yes able to delete Carthage from Mac successfully. It worked (y)

Comment: Follow the steps and I will suggest even before installation, Uninstall all the installed version of Carthege. I will work in lot better way. All the best!

Comment: This command will work if you are on OPEN network (no VPN/proxy)

Comment: Used this steps again today with npm instead of Homebrew